# QueryDsl - dynamic subquery in collection expression

Tags: collections, expression, querydsl

I am just looking for ideas to my scenario described below with spring data JPA and query DSL.
I would like to translate the following statement

```
select * from document doc1
where doc1.name = <name> and doc1.date in (
 (select max(doc2.date) from document doc2 where doc2.type = <type2>) ,
 (select max(doc3.date) from document doc3 where doc3.type = <type3>) )
```

into query DSL. "Name" and "type1" .. "typen" are passed as params. As you can see the query should get the max(date) for certain type of documents.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
query.select(doc1).from(doc1)
     .where(doc1.date.in(
       subquery.select(doc2.date.max())
               .from(doc2).where(doc2.type.in(...)))
     .fetch()
```

Comment: Hi Timo, thank you for reply. I was not able to resolve my problem. I am looking something like that:     query.from(doc1)
                 .where(doc1.name.eq(param1))
                 .where(doc1.date.in(<unique output of subquery1/doc2>, 
        <unique output of subquery2/doc3>))